Why do these for-each and value-of tags in XSLT not select the values properly?
For class we're supposed to write an XSLT file that takes in our XML file, filters out parts of it and then displays some data from what's left in a new XML file. In my case there's a wrapper "InvoiceList" which contains six "Invoice" tags. After applying the XSLT it's supposed to filter out any Invoice with a "PerformanceDate" before 2010, and then display some data of the rest of the XMLs. Below is a small example of the initial XML, the XSLT, and the resulting XML code (there's multiple invoices with many more tags but I hope this is enough to show the issue).
Initial XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceList>
    <Invoice>
        <NumbersAndInfo>
            <PerformanceDate>2017-08-08</PerformanceDate>
        </NumbersAndInfo>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <NumbersAndInfo>
            <PerformanceDate>2009-11-07</PerformanceDate>
        <NumbersAndInfo>
    </Invoice>
</InvoiceList>

XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <InvoiceList>
            <xsl:for-each select="/InvoiceList/Invoice[substring(NumbersAndInfos/PerformanceDate, 1, 4) > 2010]">
                <Invoice>
                    <PerformanceDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NumbersAndInfo/PerformanceDate"/>
                    </PerformanceDate>

Resulting XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><InvoiceList/>
Since the actual code has multiple tags I've tried several variations through them, like selecting the absolute path instead of the relative path, removing the first / in the select, selecting //Invoice[...], and I've checked that the XPath is valid by just applying it directly to the XML. I know for the for-each loop the issue has to be the condition [substring(NumbersAndInfo/PerformanceDate, 1, 4) > 2010], since removing that at least creates the tags after (here just ), though none of the values get inserted properly no matter what variation I've tried.
We're using "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers" and the "Xalan 2.7.1" Java Processor for XSLT.
Any help is appreciated!
Edit: It seems like the mistake came from something being messed up in the run configuration of Eclipse, when I reset that and went through it step by step it finally gave me the correct output. (It was mentioned that here I wrote "NumbersAndInfo" and "NumbersAndInfos" at seperate points, that wasn't present in the file itself though, I just messed up when I wrote the question)

Please provide a [mcve] that we can run as is, without having to guess the rest of your code.

Best to NOT clip the end of XML/XSLT here on your sample code provided.

Does filter before 2010not mean &gt;=2010?

The reason for the failure of the XPath to select anything could be simply a mistyping of the XML element name NumbersAndInfo in the XPath as NumbersAndInfos.
With that correction the code works fine.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <InvoiceList>
          <xsl:for-each select="/InvoiceList/Invoice[number(substring(NumbersAndInfo/PerformanceDate, 1, 4)) > 2010]">
              <Invoice>
                  <PerformanceDate>
                      <xsl:value-of select="NumbersAndInfo/PerformanceDate"/>
                  </PerformanceDate>
              </Invoice>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </InvoiceList>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Added a copy just for future viewers.  Nice setup on a sample of use in the link :)

You can also use a so called Identity Transform XSLT pattern.
It will copy/output the entire input XML except <Invoice> elements that were specified in the 2nd template.
Input XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceList>
    <Invoice>
        <NumbersAndInfo>
            <PerformanceDate>2017-08-08</PerformanceDate>
        </NumbersAndInfo>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <NumbersAndInfo>
            <PerformanceDate>2009-11-07</PerformanceDate>
        </NumbersAndInfo>
    </Invoice>
</InvoiceList>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"
               encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!--Identity transform-->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Invoice[NumbersAndInfo/PerformanceDate[number(substring(., 1, 4)) &lt; 2010]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<InvoiceList>
  <Invoice>
    <NumbersAndInfo>
      <PerformanceDate>2017-08-08</PerformanceDate>
    </NumbersAndInfo>
  </Invoice>
</InvoiceList>

